# Convert PDF to high quality JPG using PHP and ImageMagick

Tags: php, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

I'm tearing my hair out.

I have a 300 DPI PDF that I want to turn into a 300 DPI JPG that's 2550x3300.  I am told ImageMagick can do this, so I get ImageMagick to work, but it only returns a JPG that is sized about 1/5 the original PDF size.

It's not the source image--I've done it with several high quality PDFs and they all have the same problem.

After scouring StackOverflow for ideas, this is what I came up with to use:

```
$im = new imagick($srcimg);
$im->setImageResolution(2550,3300);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->writeImage($targetimg);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

But it still doesn't work.

I also have tried using $img->resizeImage() to resize the JPG, but then it comes out at really bad quality, if the right size.

Totally stumped.  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the resolution before reading the image in. Please [see this comment on the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php#96182) - see if that will work.

Comment: If I put setImageResolution first, the class hasn't been declared yet.  If I do $im = new imagick(), then $im->setImageResolution, then $im->readImage($srcimg), I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Can not process empty Imagick object' in ...

Comment: try using `$im->setResolution()` on the empty object (see nots for `Imagick::setResolution` on the manual)

Comment: Yes--just did this and I got it to work, although only 300,300 was needed.  The trick was switching the order and using setResolution instead of setImageResolution.  Thanks!

Comment: This is so right, thank you. Everyone repeat: Set the resolution before reading the image in. Also, use methods like setResolution and not setImageResolution, otherwise it errors out. That tripped me up.

Answer (score 14):

This would be the correct way, the quality will improve.

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(300, 300);
$im->readImage($srcimg);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->writeImage($targetimg);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this is still valid in 2023 for php7+